# Javafx Media - Music not playing after exporting project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, mp3, media-player

My Problem seems to be rather small but I just can't find a solution that works.

I'm trying to play background music in a game using javafx MediaPlayer which works perfectly fine as long as i run it in eclipse but as soon as i export my project as a runnable jar and try to open it, something's going wrong.

To specify the problem, here's what's happening excactly:

When trying to run the jar **without** playing/looping the music but still creating a new Mp3Player, everything works. (GUI is showing up and other stuff...)

When trying to run the jar **with** the music playing/looping, literally nothing is showing up. So i concluded reading the path to the soundfile is causing some trouble but i just can't figure out how to solve it.

The Mp3Player class:

```
public class Mp3Player implements Serializable{ 

private String filepath;
private Media m;
private MediaPlayer mp;     

private boolean musicPlaying;

public Mp3Player(boolean musicPlaying){
    //Necessary because this creates an new JavaFX-Thread!
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel(); 
    this.musicPlaying=musicPlaying;
}

public void playSound(){
    loadData();            
    mp.play();      
}

public void loopSound(){
    loadData();     
    mp.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    mp.play();
}

public void stopSound(){        
    mp.stop();
}

public void pauseSound(){
    mp.pause();
}

public void resumeSound(){
    mp.play();
} 

public void setVolume(double d){
    mp.setVolume(d);
}    

public void setFilePath(String filepath){       
    this.filepath=filepath;
}

private void nullifyAll(){      
    m=null;
    mp=null;
}

/**
 * Has to be called before playing a sound file
 */
private void loadData(){
    nullifyAll();       
    //m = new Media("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir").replace('\\', '/') + "/" + filepath);       
    try {
        m = new Media(Mp3Player.class.getResource("/Sounds/Reformat.mp3").toURI().toString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp= new MediaPlayer(m);
    if(musicPlaying)
        mp.setVolume(GameInformation.currentGameVolume);
    else
        mp.setVolume(GameInformation.currentEffectVolume);
}
```

Thank you for your help ;)

**EDIT**                                                                         Finally i got it to work. Setting the volume of the MediaPlayer directly after initializing it was causing some trouble. However for the following code works fine for me.

```
private void loadData(){
    nullifyAll();   

    try {
        m = new Media(Mp3Player.class.getResource("/Sounds/Reformat.mp3").toURI().toString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp = new MediaPlayer(m);    

    if(musicPlaying)
        setVolume(GameInformation.currentGameVolume);
    else
        setVolume(GameInformation.currentEffectVolume);
}
```

Comment: Check the contents of the jar file from the command line (`jar -tf myJarFile.jar`), and see if there is a `/Sounds/Reformat.mp3` entry. If not, something has gone wrong in the process of building the jar (you will probably need to modify project settings in Eclipse).

Comment: @James_D  I'm not used to command line but jar -tf myJarFile.jar doesn't work. It says "jar" is spelled wrong or could no be found. Anyways i extracted the jar using winRar and there is a Sounds folder with Reformat.mp3 in it. Oddly there is only such folder if i export the project as a runnable jar but not if i export it as a "normal" jar file.

Comment: That suggests there is something wrong in your Eclipse setup. If you export it as a runnable jar, so the file is there, does it work correctly? If not I recommend you log the value of `Mp3Player.class.getResource("/Sounds/Reformat.mp3")` to see how it is resolving it.

Comment: @James_D The runnable jar does not work either. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do i log the value of it ?